# Get only the month from DateTime -> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in Database

Tags: php, database

[My Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkEXh.png)
Hello, it's me, again, I'm trying to get the Month, year and date from the DateTime from my database, but I actually need to get this as 3 separate variables, so let's suppose, $year = dateYear, $month = dateMonth and $day = dateday. I just cant get it to separate, Already looked into the other comments that have the same title as mine, but they really didn't help much. Here's what I got:

I tried dividing it...

get the date from database:

```
<?php 
        include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
        $id = $_SESSION['userId']; 
        $dBname = "infosensor";
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBname);

        $sql = "SELECT dias FROM `$id`;";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($resultCheck > 0)
        {
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
          {
            echo $row['dias'];
          }
        }
      ?>
```

I found the solution guys:

```
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $row['dias'])))."</br>";
$month = date('m', strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $row['dias'])));
$year = date('y', strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $row['dias'])));
$month = date('d', strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $row['dias'])));

$hour = date('h', strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $row['dias'])));
$minute = date('i', strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $row['dias'])));
$second = date('s', strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $row['dias'])));

//We can use H:i:s for hour, minute, second too it would be like this:
//echo date('H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $row['dias'])))."</br>";
```

Comment: What format is the date you are retrieving from the database? Is it a unix timestamp, or something else?

Comment: it is timestamp -> current_timestamp

Comment: Cool - let me write you an answer :)

Comment: Your query has FROM cluase with $id. are you storing table name in SESSION?

Comment: @Vantiya Nop, It is because the ID that user logs in corresponds to his table, each user has it's own table

Comment: My project involves a bunch of information for each user, that's why...

Comment: $row['dias']; Is this the date you're storging into DB Table?

Comment: Yes, the name of the row is dias... I will edit the post so you can see my table

Answer (score 1):

The function you want is [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) - it will take a Unix timestamp and convert it to any format you want. You can either retrieve an entire date-time string, like this:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

or you can retrieve each value separately, like this:

```
$year = date("Y", $timestamp);
```

The link above shows you all the formats you might want to use. For example:

```
$month = date("F", $timestamp); // November
$month = date("m", $timestamp); // 11 (with leading zero if necessary)
$month = date("M", $timestamp); // Nov
$month = date("n", $timestamp); // 11 
$month = date("t", $timestamp); // 30 (number of days in this month)
```

Now, it looks like your "timestamp" is a MySQL timestamp (YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS). PHP has a function [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert any date string into a Unix timestamp:

```
strtotime ( $timestamp );
```

So the final step would be:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime ($timestamp) );
```

or:

```
$year = date("Y",  strtotime ($timestamp) );
```

If all else fails, you can use the [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function!

```
$year = date("Y", $timestamp); // let's say 2019-10-30 16:59:26

$exp1 = explode(" ", $timestamp);

echo $exp1[0]; // 2019-10-30
echo $exp1[1]; // 16:59:26

$date = explode("-", $exp1[0]);
$time = explode(":", $exp1[1]);

echo $date[0]; // 2019
echo $date[1]; // 10
echo $date[2]; // 30
echo $time[0]; // 16
echo $time[1]; // 59
echo $time[2]; // 26
```

Comment: Will I still need the loop? Or I can just take it off the loop?

Comment: For some reason the year I'm getting is 1970

Comment: Yeah, sorry - you have a MySQL timestamp, not a Unix timestamp. I've added a fix to the bottom of my answer :)

Comment: Ok, let me try one more thing... :)

Comment: Hmm, this time it's no printing.

Comment: I searched up, I got it with this:  echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $row['dias'])));

Comment: Yess, GG's hahaha, Thank you for the help too

Answer (score 1):

if you want extra columns from mysql query then try this

```
SELECT MONTH(timestamp) as month,day(timestamp) as day,year(timestamp) as year;
```

reference[month](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_month.asp) [year](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_year.asp) [day](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_day.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use 
`$month= date("M",strtotime ($timestamp) );`
instead of other codes